# What's wrong at setting Java Home in Visual Studio Code for enabling Apex Tests?

Tags: apex, vs-code, java

I wanna enable Apex Tests in my workspace in VS Code, but I am unable to find out what is wrong.

Here are my possibilities:

[image]

Here is the setting that I am putting...

```
{"salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" }
```

[image]

But, all the time the error message is shown.

Here is the ouput of java version

```
(.venv) oalpb@itajuba:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in the image you are setting the key:value in the value field, you should just set `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

[image: SETTING EXAMPLE]

If you open the json view, you will see the error more clearly

This is opened using the button at the top right

[image: open settings in json]

Java home should be in this format

[image: json settings]

Comment: Considering your screenshot I have put only "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64" instead of "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" and it worked! Thank you!